# Trying to add a Javascript widget to Wordpress but keeps saying SKIN ID is not set

Tags: javascript, wordpress, widget, skin

I have a javascript code I need to add to Wordpress that I am pulling from a program called 'Wellness Living,' if anyone is familiar. I am using the code block to paste the javascript widget code to wordpress and it keeps saying the "skin id is not set,?" What does this mean, is there something else in Wordpress you need to do to post Javascript codes?

Tried posting a javascript code (widget) into the code block in Wordpress and keep getting and error. Expected it to work but didn't.